# Calculate hash for XAdES referenced data

Tags: java, digital-signature

I'm validating XAdES signature. I'm iterating the References in the SignedInfo. For each Reference I take the `Node` (or file in case of XAdES detached) and I want to calculate the data hash.

The Reference has Transform that indicates using the  "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#base64" algorithm in it.

Here my trouble starts, because I am unable to transform the `Node` to `Base64`.

I would use the `XMLSignature.validate(..)` to do the work for me, but I need to store the calculated hash (not only the one present DigestValue, event though they should be the same), so I have to calculate it..

How to transform the referenced data?

Note: There can be also other transform algorithms used.